# Elasticsearch painless script error

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I have no Java experience and I have an issue with elasticsearch painless script language. (the name painless it's not well chosen).

For the following code I get the error:

```
{"lang": "painless",
"inline": "float price = doc['newPrice'] > 0.0 ? doc['price'] / doc['newPrice'] : 0; _score * params.constant * price",
"params": {"constant": 1.2}}}}
```

> Cannot apply [>] operation to types
>   [org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues.Doubles] and
>   [java.lang.Double].

I tied to cast it as float with (float) doc['newPrice'] > 0 with the same error.

Then I changed to `"Double price = ((Double)doc['discountPrice'] > 0.0) ? doc['price'] / doc['discountPrice'] : 0; _score * params.constant * price",`

And received:

> 'Cannot cast from [Double] to [double].'

Can somebody help me, tried lots of variations with similar kind of errors.
Damn painless language...

Comment: I agree, this language is harder to use and has more "gotchas" than C

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You're simply [missing the `.value`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-painless.html#_accessing_doc_values_from_painless) to access the field value.

Your script needs to be like this instead:

```
double price = doc['newPrice'].value > 0.0 ? doc['price'].value / doc['newPrice'].value : 0; _score * params.constant * price
```

Comment: Val, do you also know how can I check if a field exists, so I can reference it's value?

Comment: You can check for `doc['newPrice'].size()`. If you get 0, then there's no value, otherwise, there's a value you can use.

Comment: @Val This is a very interesting question on painless script. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53476036/check-value-exists-in-params-array-using-elasticsearch-painless-script

Answer (score 6):

```
doc['newPrice']
```

is different from

```
doc['newPrice'].value
```

You should use the later